# Delete all extended properties from a mailbox using EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

we are connecting to office 365 mailbox using EWS and creating extended properties on outgoing emails, and we have reached the limit on max number of extended properties can be created. We create the property while sending an email and use it after we send it. But we don't store the property Ids.

Is there an option to delete all or some of the properties without having the property id?

Or, can we get a list of properties or IDs of the properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that with EWS or MAPI,

> > we are connecting to office 365 mailbox using EWS and creating extended properties on outgoing emails, and we have reached the limit on max number of extended properties can be created.

You shouldn't get into this situation in the first place if you use Extended properties correctly. Eg your app shouldn't be creating random new extended properties, you should just use one property and then in the Value for that property store a Json string with the key/value combination you need. In that way you will never get to the point of named property exhaustion because you are only using one property that can have an infinite number of Key/Value pairs for whatever application you want.

Comment: Hi Glen, you are absolutely right. We should not have created new properties each time, instead we should use the same ID for each of the emails. But, we have erroneously made this mess and fixed our code. But, the problem is we need to create one new property and we cannot because it already reached the max limit. We have also tried to read the item.extendedproperties of the sent emails but we don't see any property in the list. We could use one of the existing ID. Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is an onPrem server then you need to move the Mailbox to another database and use the DoNotPreserveMailboxSignature switch which will reset the Named properties https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2011/01/24/obviating-outlook-client-restarts-after-mailbox-moves/ . If its Office365 you need to talk to support as they will be only people that can resolve the issue for you.

Comment: This is Office365 and we are trying to talk to them. By this time, I was able to read the extended property of the emails from the Sent Items in Outlook using Outlook Spy. We are using that ID for now. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

[This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633629(v%3Dexchg.80)) seems to suggest that deleting extended properties *is* possible, provided you have the right information to construct an [ExtendedPropertyDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.extendedpropertydefinition?view=exchange-ews-api).

Comment: The only problem here is that I don't have the IDs of the properties and for that reason I cannot construct the ExtendedPropertyDefinition. Thanks, Richard.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the extended property of the emails from the Sent Items in Outlook using Outlook Spy. We are using that ID for now. This is not an option to delete the properties from Office 365. But it gave me the ID of an existing property that we can use for the future emails.